# Display popup when there are unsved inputs on dropdown change in JSF

Tags: jsf, valuechangelistener

How to display of popup when any of the two dropdowns selection changed and input values are modified using JSF. I am using valuechangelistener.
I have added a flag in my Mbean, if any of the input changes, this flag will be true. on change of the value of the dropdown, if this flag is true I need to show popup, but this is not coming

Comment: Would be great to see your .xhtml code snippet!

Comment: Please read [tour] and [ask] and [mcve] and improve your question

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the`<f:ajax/>` tag inside of your dropdowns the following code snippet (especially the "onevent" attribute) might be useful:

```
   <f:ajax render="itemsDataTable" 
    onevent="function(data) { if (data.status === 'success') { 
   alert('it works') ;} }"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried this, but not able to get the updated values from Mbean to javascript.

Comment: It should be possible to use the expression language also in javascript. Have you already tried to use #{mBean.myValue} in your script?

Comment: Yes, I have used that. But the value of #{mbean.myValue} is not reflecting. My scenario is like this: I have two dropdown menu(h:selectOneMenu) and the input text fileds corresponding to that. If the input fields are modified by user, and while changing any of the dropdown menu, I need to display the popup.